# Find the eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $ A = \begin{bmatrix}
          4&0&0\\
          0&4&0\\
          0&0&0
          \end{bmatrix}$

I understand the eigenvalues to be: $\lambda_1 = 4$, $\lambda_2 = 4$, $\lambda_3 = 0$.

I am unable to compute the corresponding eigenvectors.

For $\lambda_1 = 4:$

$(A-\lambda_1I)v = 0$

$\Rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}
              0&0&0\\
              0&0&0\\
              0&0&-4
              \end{bmatrix}v=0$

after rref we get:

$\Rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}
              0&0&1\\
              0&0&0\\
              0&0&0
              \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
              v_1\\
              v_2\\
              v_3
              \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
              0\\
              0\\
              0
              \end{bmatrix} $

with 2 free variables I am not sure how to compute a distictive $v_1$

I only know from wolfram that $v_1 = (1,0,0)$, $v_2 = (0,1,0)$, $v_3 = (0,0,1)$

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that the eigenspace of 4 is two-dimensional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix  $A$ is already diagonal so the columns are the eigenvectors.

For the $v_3 = (0,0,1)$ it is clear because that $\lambda_3 = 0$.